# how to cache CI active record which does not use query() function

Tags: codeigniter, caching, activerecord

Yes,I understand I can cache queries like this

```
$CI->db->cache_on();
$query = $CI->db->query("select photo,gender from users where id=".$id);
$CI->db->cache_off();
```

But I need it in this way

```
$CI->db->cache_on();
$CI->db->select(array('photo','gender'))->from('users')->where('id',$id);
$CI->db->cache_off();
$row = $CI->db->get()->row_array();
```

I'm getting the data,but nothing is created in `cache/` directory . So I think it's not being cached.
Can someone please help on how to cache in the second case?

**Update**

when I do this

```
 $CI->db->cache_on();
 $CI->db->select(array('photo','gender'))->from('users')->where('id',$id)->get();
 $CI->db->cache_off();
 $row = $CI->db->row_array();
```

PDO driver says, `row_array()` is an undefined function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
$CI->db->cache_on();
$CI->db->select(array('photo','gender'))->from('users')->where('id',$id);
$CI->db->cache_off();
$row = $CI->db->get()->row_array();
```

move the `get` method to be called before the `cache_off` method is called, like this

```
$CI->db->cache_on();
$query = $CI->db->select(array('photo','gender'))->from('users')->where('id',$id)->get();
$CI->db->cache_off();
$row = $query->row_array();
```

Then it is working like your manual query :)

It is doing that because the query doesn't run until you call the `get` method, hence why the `row_array` doesn't exist